Why cant i get this decal to wrap around my object
sorry if this is obvious but I'm still new to 3D. why is my decal or label getting cut off or mirrored at the halfway point of the cylinder/jar? it cuts off if I check remove backface is the options . Im using the Sanctus Library Decal addon. It shows up full if i scale it down on the jar. help please?



Questions about third-party addons are off-topic on this site, and probably not everybody knows this addon. But if it uses Blender's Shrinkwrap modifier, I guess this question is similar to: Image not shrinkwrapping around my sphere object.

Hello @M.Ali, welcome to BSE. While I don't know the addon you mention, it probably doesn't operate differently than how people do manually. This question probably answers the issue from a perspective of manually making mesh-based decals. If it doesn't solve your issue, please [edit] your question to better explain what didn't work, show how the addon operates, ...
